# Xlookup Macro re-opening already open file

Tags: excel, vba, xlookup

I need to automate a report I run for when I'm out of office, but this one section keeps failing me. How do I stop it from asking me to open an already open file? I cannot figure out what I missed. This is later repeated again in code elsewhere and causes the same issue as I'm referencing the same file.

```
ChDir "H:\SCOSBaker\Backlog Reports\Oracle Backlog"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
("H:\SCOSBaker\Backlog Reports\Oracle Backlog\Backlog_" & Format(Now(), "MMDDYY") & ".xlsx")

Dim FilenameSufffix As String
    FilenameSuffix = Format(Now(), "MMDDYY")
    
Dim XLSXFilename As String
    XLSXFilename = "Backlog_" & FilenameSuffix & ".xlsx"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=XLOOKUP(RC[3],[XLSXFilename]Copy_Of_Query_SO_Config_Lines!C19,[XLSXFilename]Copy_Of_Query_SO_Config_Lines!C7)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```vb
Const FPATH As String = "H:\SCOSBaker\Backlog Reports\Oracle Backlog\"

Dim wb As Workbook, fName As String

fName = "Backlog_" & Format(Now(), "MMDDYY") & ".xlsx"

On Error Resume Next
Set wb = Workbooks(fName) 'try to get a reference: ignore error if not open
On Error GoTo 0           'stop ignoring errors

'if not open then open it...
If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Workbooks.Open(FPATH & fName)
```

Comment: Assume there are 2 files both having the name ```fName```. File A sits in folder ```FPATH``` and file B sits in some other folder. If file B is already opened then the line ```Set wb = Workbooks(fName)``` will not check if file A is opened. Maybe an extra line like ```If Not wb Is Nothing Then If wb.FullName <> FPATH & fName Then ...``` would be useful (with proper indenting of course). +1

Comment: Yes you could try that.  I didn't get from your question that you actually had two files with the same name but in different locations...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not the OP. The OP did not mention that, it's just something to take into account

Comment: @CristianBuse - sorry not paying attention today...

Comment: @TimWilliams it is 1 file in 1 location, referenced multiple times. that fix is resulting in the same outcome, prompting to open file that is already open

Comment: Exactly which line is causing the prompt?